# Fractal Tree in P5.js

Tags: javascript, recursion, graphics, p5.js, fractals

I've been trying to create a simple fractal tree program using P5.js, for displaying on a website, but I seem to be getting unexpected behavior. Code and picture attached.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1920, 1080);
}

function draw() {
  background(10);
  x = 1920/2
  y = 1080/2
  fractalDraw(x, y, 5, 0)
}

function fractalDraw(nodeX, nodeY, numNodes, sideFlag){
  offset = 10 * numNodes
  leftNodeX = nodeX - offset
  rightNodeX = nodeX + offset
  topNodeY = nodeY - offset
  botNodeY = nodeY + offset
  
  if(sideFlag === -1){                                 //Leftside draw
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, topNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255)
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, botNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255);
  }
  else if(sideFlag === 1){                            //Rightside draw
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, topNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, botNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255);
  }
  else{                                              //Starting draw
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, topNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255)
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, botNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, topNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, botNodeY)
    stroke(255,255,255);
  }
  
  if(numNodes === 1){                              //Recursion Base Case
    return 1
  }
  else{                                            //Recursive calls
    fractalDraw(leftNodeX, topNodeY, numNodes-1, -1)
    fractalDraw(leftNodeX, botNodeY, numNodes-1, -1)
    fractalDraw(rightNodeX, topNodeY, numNodes-1, 1)
    fractalDraw(rightNodeX, botNodeY, numNodes-1, 1)
  }
}
```

[Fractals not fractaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24qic.png)

I'm using recursive calls, and it seems only my first recursive call is running, then the entire draw loop restarts in a different starting position than intended once the first (and only the first) recursive call finishes. Also I had some weird behavior when using small number of branch layers (3 or less).

Comment: I think this will be pretty tough to do without pushing/popping the context. What's your strategy here exactly? There's an example in the docs: https://p5js.org/examples/simulate-recursive-tree.html

Comment: The hope is to build a very simple fractal tree, with number of branch layers equal to numNodes, with each branch layer being shorter than the previous (offset variable) and at 45 degrees from the starting branch node for a given branch layer.

Comment: I understand the goal, but you haven't stated what your approach/algorithm/strategy to achieve it is. The code here isn't like a typical algorithm I'd expect to draw a tree (see the link for the typical algorithm). Normally, you'd push/pop/translate/rotate the canvas to draw each subtree. I suppose you could compute the coordinates by hand, and maybe that's what you're trying to do, but that seems like making things unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. But your guess was correct, I'm drawing the tree without using an actual tree structure - I'm using the XY coordinates of the subtrees, then creating new branches based on those XY coordinates. 

For the start, I draw an X on the middle of the grid, then the 4 recursive calls are for the 4 points of the first branch - they create a new branch from the XY points of the first branch, and I control which side using the sideFlag (left or right). 

Using coordinates makes it easier later to modify HOW the fractals connect - lines, curves, etc.

Comment: Thanks, and is there a reason you don't want to use the easy way, out of curiosity? [Drawing fractal trees only using line function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172369/drawing-fractal-trees-only-using-line-function) may be useful. Even though it's Processing (and Python), the logic is mostly variables and math ops that translate to any language. I'm pretty sure you'll need trig functions to make this happen.

Comment: I'm writing this for use by non-programmers, it's a demo for design oriented students, so I'm more interested in explaining how to do this geometrically, instead of giving a programming lesson on the tree data structure and tree traversals. I wrote a working version of this using trees in Python and it worked first time, but my students just had lost expressions looking at it :')

Comment: Also your link was really nice, I'll use it to correct my work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you don't define your variables with `var`, `let` or `const`, and so all your variables are implicitly declared as global variables, which is the cause of havoc. The values of `leftNodeX` and similar variables are modified by the recursive calls, and so when these recursive calls return, these variables no longer have their intended values, and the next recursive call will get arguments that no longer make sense.

There are also a few other issues:

- The offset should not diminish with a constant. If you start with `numNodes` equal to 5, then at different recursion depths, you'll have an `offset` of 50, then 40, 30, 20, ... This is not ideal. This sequences should be a *geometric* sequence, i.e. the `offset` should reduce by a *factor*, not by a constant. To achieve that, it will be easier to just pass the offset as argument instead of the number of nodes.
- The very first line is not drawn, because the stroke was not set. Be aware that the line is drawn when the call `line()` is made, and you only need to call `stroke` once: it is a configuration for any of the next calls to `line` (and other drawing functions). So you could move that `stroke()` call in your setup.
- To support other screen sizes, don't hard-code the canvas size, but use the browser's information (together with CSS) about the screen size (or alternatively, the window's size).
- p5 will continue to call `draw` forever. As you have no animation, there is no need for that: one call is enough. You can indicate this by adding a call to p5's `noLoop`
- [Should I use semicolons in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/537632/5459839)

Correction:

```js
function setup() {
  // Use browser information to set size (see also CSS settings for body)
  createCanvas(screen.width, screen.height);
  // Call stroke before drawing
  stroke(255,255,255);
}

function draw() {
  background(10);
  // Define variables with const 
  const x = width >> 1; // Use integer division
  const y = height >> 1;
  // Pass the initial offset instead of the number of nodes
  fractalDraw(x, y, width >> 2, 0);
  noLoop(); // Avoid repeating calls to draw()
}

function fractalDraw(nodeX, nodeY, offset, sideFlag){
  // Define variables with const (here was the most dramatic bug) 
  const leftNodeX = nodeX - offset;
  const rightNodeX = nodeX + offset;
  const topNodeY = nodeY - offset;
  const botNodeY = nodeY + offset;
  
  if(sideFlag === -1){
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, topNodeY);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, botNodeY);
  }
  else if(sideFlag === 1){
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, topNodeY);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, botNodeY);
  }
  else{
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, topNodeY);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, botNodeY);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, topNodeY);
    line(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, botNodeY);
  }
  
  if(offset <= 1){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    // The offset should decrease by a factor, not by a constant
    offset >>= 1; // For example: integer divide by 2
    fractalDraw(leftNodeX, topNodeY, offset, -1);
    fractalDraw(leftNodeX, botNodeY, offset, -1);
    fractalDraw(rightNodeX, topNodeY, offset, 1);
    fractalDraw(rightNodeX, botNodeY, offset, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

There is also an issue with the "tree" shape your code draws. I assume that lines should all be connected, but in case the flag is -1 or 1 (so all cases except the initial call), two out of four of the recursive calls will pass coordinates that might not have been used by a previous `line` call, and so you sometimes get disconnected lines.

I can only guess which shape you were going for, but here is an alternative you may want to consider:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(screen.width, screen.height);
  stroke(255,255,255);
}

function draw() {
  background(10);
  const x = width >> 1
  const y = height >> 1;
  fractalDraw(x, y, x, y, width >> 2);
  noLoop();
}

function fractalDraw(fromX, fromY, nodeX, nodeY, offset){
  line(fromX, fromY, nodeX, nodeY);
  if (offset < 1) {
    return;
  }
  const leftNodeX = nodeX - offset;
  const rightNodeX = nodeX + offset;
  const topNodeY = nodeY - offset;
  const botNodeY = nodeY + offset;

  offset >>= 1;
  fractalDraw(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, topNodeY, offset);
  fractalDraw(nodeX, nodeY, leftNodeX, botNodeY, offset);
  fractalDraw(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, topNodeY, offset);
  fractalDraw(nodeX, nodeY, rightNodeX, botNodeY, offset);
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I'm sure you can tell, but I'm not natively a Javascript programmer - I mostly work in C, where the variable hierarchy is a lot simpler (in my opinion). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yea implicit globals sound crazy to me, but maybe it's just the system I'm used to haha. I've marked your answer as accepted, thank you again! Out of curiosity, does TypeScript also do implicit globals? Or are variables properly in scope like in C/Java/Python?

Comment: No, in TypeScript this is not allowed. In JavaScript it is frowned upon, and is only allowed because of the extreme backwards compatibility that is maintained (and this sad design mistake existed since the beginning of JS). With "use strict" (i.e. *strict mode* -- which is best practice) it will not be allowed in JavaScript either.